# How can I make a "block" with seekbar and text?

Tags: android, textview, seekbar

How can do that

[image]

How can I put in the same block two text and a seekbar?

Can I put them together?

This is my current (poor) code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_libretto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button"

        />


 <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/ProgressBar01"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10px"
    android:paddingRight ="10px"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:max="10"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
    android:secondaryProgress="0"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`RelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html).